# How can I make a jquery ui slider with two handles that "push" eachother?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I want to use jquery ui to make a slider with two handles that maintain a minimum space between them.  If the left handle tries to cross the right handle, the right handle should be pushed along.  And vice-versa.  Here's an example (nevermind the overlapping, that's not important):

http://jsfiddle.net/SP5VQ/

It works so long as the movement is slow but if the mouse moves too fast, it fails in the "pushing" scenario.  I think that setting the sliders values from within the 'slider' event might be at fault.

Comment: I've tested your jsFiddle in Chrome, Firefox, and IE8 with no issues when moving the mouse too fast after holding on to a handle. Please try your jsFiddle using a different mouse as the one your using may have a defective left-click button (a momentary break during moving is all that takes to produce the issue you've describe). Also, remove the "nevermind" portion in your answer, as that contradicts asking for a minimum space between the handles. Having said that, you might want to revise your Question to ask for how to have minimum space between each handle. Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked.  I copied the code from `$.ui.slider.prototype._slide` and removed the part that checked if the left handle was greater than the right handle.  Works well now.

http://jsfiddle.net/Nk8ap/

```
        $.ui.slider.prototype._slide = function ( event, index, newVal ) {
          var otherVal,
            newValues,
            allowed;

          if ( this.options.values && this.options.values.length ) {
            otherVal = this.values( index ? 0 : 1 );
            if ( newVal !== this.values( index ) ) {
              newValues = this.values();
              newValues[ index ] = newVal;
              // A slide can be canceled by returning false from the slide callback
              allowed = this._trigger( "slide", event, {
                handle: this.handles[ index ],
                value: newVal,
                values: newValues
              } );
              otherVal = this.values( index ? 0 : 1 );
              if ( allowed !== false ) {
                this.values( index, newVal, true );
              }
            }
          } else {
            if ( newVal !== this.value() ) {
              // A slide can be canceled by returning false from the slide callback
              allowed = this._trigger( "slide", event, {
                handle: this.handles[ index ],
                value: newVal
              } );
              if ( allowed !== false ) {
                this.value( newVal );
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: I think this is much better than the default behaviour of the UI slider. Nice work.